# DateTime.Now inside object initialiser

Tags: c#, .net

If I do:

```
var foo = new Foo
{
    Created = DateTime.Now,
    Modified = DateTime.Now
};
```

is there by any chance any compiler optimisation going on which ensures that the two date properties are equal, or must I read `Now` into a temporary variable first myself?

Comment: There's no guarantee, but DateTime usually has a resolution of 15msecs, so it's practically impossible to have different values. Said that, if you want a 100% security, then use a temp variable.

Comment: @Gusman The probability to fail is quite high. In my tests (Debug version) I never saw more that a few thousands tries before `Created == Modified` fails.

Comment: @AlexD hmmm, maybe your computer is too slow? I can run more than 100k tests without any problem... Anyway, as I said if the process is critical then to use a temp variable is the way to go.

Comment: @Gusman I added my test to the post.

Comment: @AlexD I didn't mean you were wrong, the test case is nearly the same for me, and I can belive it happens on your machine, just stated it happened on my machine very rarely, I think that will be because of the processor type and speed, just that.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with processor speed.  Just because the RTC resolution is 15ms (actually more like 10ms) doesn't mean that you're guaranteed to have equal values from two subsequent calls.  You very well could hit one just before the clock tick and one just after.

Comment: You should not make such assumption in your code. By being explicit, it will be clearer to future reader.

Comment: @MattJohnson One may argue that the faster processor is, the faster `DateTime.Now` returns. If time for both calls (and corresponding assignments) is approaching zero, the probability to hit the resolution border is approaching zero too.

Comment: Only for a single pair of occurrences.  The more you have of them, the higher the odds of a hit.  Anyway, we're getting off topic. Indeed, it is better to be explicit in the code and only call `DateTime.Now` once.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not supposed to omit `DateTime.Now`, regardless of optimization. To ensure that fields initialized to the same value, consider something like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    public DateTime Created;
    public DateTime Modified;
    public Foo(DateTime dt)
    {
        Created = Modified = dt;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo(DateTime.Now);
```

The probability that `Created != Modified`, if they are initialized separately, is rather high. The following loops on my system (in `DEBUG` and `RELEASE`) never makes more that a few sousand iterations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        Modified = DateTime.Now
    };
    if (foo.Created != foo.Modified)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", foo.Created.Ticks, foo.Modified.Ticks, i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: couldn't    
Created = Modified = DateTime.Now 
work as well?

Comment: Creating a constructor just for the sake of setting two separate properties with the same value is overkill.

Comment: @DaniDev Yes, but `struct` does not allow explicit parameterless constructors and in this case I thought that `struct` fits better that `class`.

Comment: @JeffMercado I think that these fields/properties can be modified independently. What is wrong with setting default values in ctor? What would be a good alternative?

Comment: You're suggesting adding a constructor to some object just to set the property values. While a constructor is helpful at times, adding it just for this purpose _is_ overkill. Considering when you could just declare a variable to determine the value to set once, and set the properties with that.

Comment: @JeffMercado Hmm... It would be canonical to have `Foo(DateTime created, DateTime modified) {Created = created; Modified = modified; }` I just suggested a simplified version of it, which utilizes the fact that values are the same. I would not consider it as overkill, but maybe it is a matter of personal preferences.